# Unset variables declared in file

Tags: bash

Say I have `object.properties`, which looks like

```
test=1
hello=2
foo=3
```

Let's say all these variables are in the environment. How can I unset all of them? i.e.

```
unset test hello foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a simple [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) loop:

```
while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
  unset "$key"
done <object.properties
```

Or, if you have bash 4.0 or newer, you can couple [`readarray`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile?s[]=readarray) (the shell builtin also known as `mapfile`) with a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
readarray -t lines <object.properties
unset "${lines[@]%%=*}"
```